# Unable to open .sps.bak database backup file with SQL Server 2012 Express edition

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express edition. Client sent me the SQL Server backup file with the extension `.sps.bak`. I am not able to open it with SSMS. Please somebody help me here.

I get the following error message.

> *Restore of database failed.
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: the
>   database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That
>   version is incompatible with this server, which is running 10.00.1600.
>   Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup or
>   use a backup that is compatible with this server*.

I cannot open the database that was developed with a professional edition on an Express edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>That's probably a Sharepoint backup. Restore it in Sharepoint, or ask for a SQL server backup</s>

Your error message shows that you are connected to a SQL 2008 server, not SQL 2012, and that the backup was performed on a SQL 2008 **R2** server. You need an R2 server, or SQL 2012, to restore it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I dont have sharepoint. hmmm let me ask the client for sql server backup.

Comment: @sri Following your additional information, this may be incorrect

Comment: Hi Podiluska, You are right. The problem was with version compatibility. Now i am able to restore the database with sql server 2012 express edition. Thanks so much for your help...